# Prolog add to list if element is not equal to string

Tags: prolog, prolog-dif, guard-clause

I am trying to create a list of pairs which have a non-null Guard element.

```
get_only_guarded(L) :-
    Guard \= null,
    findall([S,D],transition(S,D,_,Guard,_),L).
```

This is what ive tried but it doesnt seem to work. What would be the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

Use `dif(Guard,null)` instead. Handle `(\=)/2` with care!

Comment: Thank you very much, didnt know about this built in function

Comment: I have trouble letting go of my GNU Prolog (it doesn't have `dif/2`). ;)

Answer (score 2):

a more 'conventional ' way to do: push the test after the instantiation

```
get_only_guarded(L) :-
    findall([S,D], (transition(S,D,_,Guard,_),Guard \= null), L).
```